# What does "tail -f " do?

Tags: tail

I don't understand the function of the option `-f` added to the `tail` command.

I know that `tail` views the "last" part of a file. The manual says that

> `-f` outputs appended data as the file grows

But I don't really understand what that means. I know the meaning of each word in the previous quotation, but I don't understand the meaning of the whole sentence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means `tail -f` command will wait for new strings in the file and show these strings dynamically. This command useful for observing log files .

For example try, `tail -f /var/log/messages`.

Answer (score 4):

You can think of -f as "follow".  When -f is added to tail, the command will not exit but waits to see if more is added to the file; that additional text will be printed by tail.  You normally kill a tail -f with ^c.

It is often used with log files that that are being written by daemons or a background user process.

`tail -f /var/log/syslog`

Answer (score 3):

If you have an active log file,program is running while writing info to log file.
you can open the log with tail -f so the log is being displayed "live".
tail -f /var/log/logfile is like constanly doing tail /var/log/logfile